# При попытке посмотреть правку, за которую получена репутация, перебрасывает на несуществующую страницу, если до этого я был на мете

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, репутация, мета, утверждённые-правки

До получения 2k репутации за правки начисляется +2 очка, и при получении этих +2 на кубке в верхнем правом углу появляется зелёненькое число. Но при попытке перейти по ссылке на эту правку, если я до этого находился **НА МЕТЕ** (https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/), меня перебрасывает не на страницу исправленного вопроса на основном сайте, а на вопрос с тем же id на мете, которого не существует.

Пример:

- Получена репутация за правку вопроса по ссылке

```
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1538788/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%91%d0%bc-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-reached-end-of-file-while-parsing
```

- Меня  перебрасывает на страницу

```
https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1538788/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%91%d0%bc-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-reached-end-of-file-while-parsing
```

При чём если я получаю репутацию не за правку, а за ответ или вопрос, то этого бага не происходит.

И всё нормально, если я перехожу по ссылке из кубка, но я до этого находился на странице основного сайта (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/).

С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: Метка [meta-tag:статус-запланировано] выставляется только сотрудниками SE для создания новой задачи в джире. Вешать эту метку на вопрос только ради метки не следует.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В начале августа [эту же проблему зарепортили на основной мете](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/391952/383809). Дело в том, что ссылка рассчитывается "относительно" текущего пути, что влечет собой описанный баг.

<s>В настоящий момент этот баг имеет на основное мете [статус-запланировано](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be) и [комментарий от сотрудника 30 августа](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/391952/positive-reputation-notification-for-edit-approvals-uses-relative-url-which-cau#comment1313221_391952), который, по идее, обещает скорое разрешение проблемы.</s>

[Баг поправлен 5 сентября 2023.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/392827/383809)

Comment: что случилось с аватакой?

Comment: @Danis менял на другую во время забастовки. А старая была фото 2016 года, пора менять, да руки не доходят.

Comment: получается через 6-8 недель починят?

Comment: @Nofate, или, вспоминая анекдот, 68 пишется без дефиса?

Comment: Много вопросов в одном стиле "approved edit goes to the wrong place" было задано после первого вопроса на MSE.